# How do i stop cursor blinking in linux console ( ex a cygwin )?

Tags: linux, cygwin

How do i stop the blinking cursor in my cygwin ? I am writing a program , Its a gaming program  using multi-threading But the cursor is blinking on the console. How do i make it stop ? How do I remove that from my console?

Comment: what a weird question. just to make sure, cygwin is just a Windows-based Linux "simulator". What is your gaming program written in? cygwin itself is not a programming language.

Comment: Does it sound wierd? Yes your right, its a windows based linux tool but all linux commands work on it. I even did some projects on mutli threading. I am intersted in creating a game. But ths cursor its annoying. I tried a command that i found on google but its not working. I want the cursor to be stopped from blinking and must be hidden so that it should not be visible

Comment: A game named as galaxy where you got a target moving which shoots you up and you got some bullets to hit it. I have planned how to do it using high scores and everything I even have the concept how to add sounds to it only think im stucked is with cursor

Comment: This game may be no use to anyone as we have UDK and many engines right now.But it makes me more cleaner and cleaner with the code and i can understand how im best in the c . Thank you

Comment: Hopefully you're trying to get the app you coded in your Linux enviroment to run on Windows for the purpose of distribution. Otherwise, I think you may find it hard getting any sympathy for 'real users' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to switch the cursor off completely or do you just want to disable the blinking? The [DECTCEM](http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECTCEM) control sequence can do the former, whereas [DECSCUSR](http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECSCUSR) can do the latter.

Unfortunately the default Cygwin console doesn't support either of those, but the "[mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com)" terminal does.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which terminal emulator you're using.

The default terminal is simply a Windows command prompt.  A very quick Google search found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/49074/non-blinking-block-cursor-in-windows-xp-command-prompt).

For mintty, to turn off blinking in the current instance, right-click, then Options, click on Looks, then disable blinking.  You can make this permanent by adding the line `CursorBlinks=0` to your `$HOME/.minttyrc`.

For xterm, middle-click and then uncheck `Enable blinking cursor`, or invoke it with the `+bc` command-line option.  There's also a `cursorBlink` X resource.  I don't seem to have anything set up to make this permanent; I guess xterm disables blinking by default.

Comment: Changes in mintty's options dialog are automatically saved to $HOME/.minttyrc, so editing that manually shouldn't be needed here.